# numpy upgrade is not happening

Tags: pandas, numpy

when i import pandas , i get following error

```
ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.9.0. 
your numpy version is 1.8.0rc1.
```

so I upgraded numpy using

```
sudo pip install numpy --upgrade --ignore-installed
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.13.3
```

When I check this , my numpy version is same and error with pandas import remains same.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.8.0rc1'
```

Please let me know how to fix this.  I am using Python 2.7.10. Issue appeared after in installed Quandl

Comment: Did you install it for the right python?

Comment: py version for package download is cp27.

Comment: for OSX  numpy = 1.8.0rc1  is pre installed version

Comment: Check the environment you are using. If you have installed and trying on the go restart the kernel once and try again.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can check the original numpy lib location.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.__version__
1.6.0
>>> print(numpy)
<module 'numpy' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.pyc'>
```

you can delete the lib, then it will be ok.